# Debian 9.1 (Stretch) default logon background image

Tags: debian, wallpaper, gdm3

I try to find the image (background) which is shown during logon screen (default installation), without any logo.
I've checked `gdm3` config and all available wallpapers, but couldn't find it. Here an example of it: 
[image: background image]

Comment: Do you mean you’re trying to find *where it is stored* (so you can change it)?

Comment: Yes, I want to find the file of background image, if it's a file. And use it as a wallpaper on another system.

Comment: Well, you’ve got a file now — you just posted it here.   I’m not clear exactly what you’re asking for.

Comment: It is an example from [gdm3 package](https://screenshots.debian.net/package/gdm3). Default installation looks the same, but I can't find that gray background image.

Comment: @peoff Your nickname means "fart" in Spanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good and complete [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534187/where-is-the-login-screen-wallpaper-for-gdm-stored).

But for those who want only a background image, they can use [this](http://noisepng.com/) with color settings `#2e3436`.